# Dart/Flutter - Hex conversion?

Tags: flutter, dart, hex

i would like to convert 'Hello' to hexadecimal

The codeUnits are :

```
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 55357, 56395]
```

I would like to obtain : `48656c6c6ff09f918b`

How to do that please ?
I used some libs 'Pinenacl', 'hex' but I obtain a wrong hexa: `48656c6c6f3d4b`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert an arbitrarily long hexadecimal string to a number in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57675661/convert-an-arbitrarily-long-hexadecimal-string-to-a-number-in-dart)

Answer (score 4):

Your result are encoded in UTF-8 and not UTF-16 (which your code units are). So you need to first encode your `String` to UTF-8 data and then convert this into hex:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String string = String.fromCharCodes([72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 55357, 56395]);
  print(string); // Hello
  print(utf8.encode(string).map((e) => e.toRadixString(16)).join()); // 48656c6c6ff09f918b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hex](https://pub.dev/packages/hex)

```
List<int> list = utf8.encode("Hello");
String hex = HEX.encode(list);
print(hex);
```

result

```
48656c6c6ff09f918b
```

Comment: You don't need to convert your `list` (which are really a `Uint8List`) into `Uint16List`.